# Need regex pattern to remove numbers at the beginning of the string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a string like below:

```
tpgtags: sham = 6john = 5tpg100 = 4tpg1 = 3ram = 2
```

I want it to be like below:

```
sham john tpg100 tpg1 ram
```

My problem is I want to remove only 2,3,5,6 and not 100 nor 1.  How do I do this?  I can't remove all numbers because it removes 100 and 1 but those are at the end of string.  I want to remove numbers are in front of string.
With `preg_split`, it is removing all numbers, so can you tell me how to remove numbers but not all numbers?

Comment: plz tell me M42,how to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
$str = 'tpgtags: sham 6john 5tpg100 4tpg1 3ram 2';
$str = preg_replace('/\s\d+/', ' ', $str);
echo $str,"\n";
```

**output:**

```
tpgtags: sham john tpg100 tpg1 ram
```

It removes all digits that are preceeded by space.

According to your edit, you want to remaove also the `=` sign, so use this:

```
$str = 'tpgtags: sham = 6john = 5tpg100 = 4tpg1 = 3ram = 2';
$str = preg_replace('/\s=\s\d+/', ' ', $str);
echo $str,"\n";
```

Comment: thnku M42 it is working can you tell me one more thing if i want to remove = also with your $str = preg_replace('/\s\d+/', ' ', $str);
.so what i do .becoz = sign was also there but i removed now it is appearing by using your regular expression

Comment: @user3668677: Sorry, I don't get you. Which `=` do you want to remove? Please, edit your question to provide a full example.